# z-index not working for <input>

Tags: html, css, forms, svg, z-index

I've got an `<svg>` that I want to surround an `<input>` text box.  I've set the `z-index` of the `<svg>` to be higher than the containing `<div>`, and the `z-index` of the `<input>` text box to be even higher, yet the `<svg>` is still on top of the `<input>` text box.

http://jsfiddle.net/6R2mf/1/

```
<form id="before-list" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="search" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Label:</label>
    <div class="ui-input-search ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear"><span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" aria-live="polite" role="status"></span>
        <input style="z-index: 10000;" autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input" name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="placeholder" data-type="search" type="text"><a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-input-clear-hidden" title="Clear text">Clear text</a>
    </div>
</form>
<svg style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1001;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="396" version="1.1" height="78">
    <path d="M37.321735818577594,19.412056931773776C91.00900384635584,19.71827132609725,306.20767155776537,15.079895914223181,359.3368606653108,21.253021635495596C412.4692927191486,27.426524157459045,410.1732367732173,50.26181430495186,356.10649891451214,56.45301593533142C302.039761055807,62.64421756571098,86.9940586922537,64.75550694155167,34.93643351307978,58.40023141777294C-17.12119166609414,52.04495589399421,-10.036532153974994,24.179328007664637,43.760747839468635,18.32136279265903C97.55802783291226,12.463397577653424,305.393552534696,22.43059390522592,357.72011347374155,23.252440127739302" stroke="#000000" fill="none" style=""></path>
</svg>
```

How can I get the input text box to be on top of the SVG?

(Using Firefox 24 & jQuery Mobile 1.4.0)

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the problem *in the question itself*. You shouldn't depend on external links as the question will become useless if they break.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6R2mf/4/

I added the following style to form

```
<form style="position: relative; z-index: 9999;" id="before-list" onsubmit="return false;">
```

---

EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/6R2mf/8/

I just added the position: relative; back in to your new fiddle, and it works again

z-index needs the element it's on to have a position: relative or fixed, or absolute for it to work

Comment: hrm, this seems to work in the fiddle, but not on the actual page.  In http://jsfiddle.net/6R2mf/7/ I added the tag outside the `<form>` and the `<svg>` is back on top.  (adding `z-index` to the outside tag works, but how do i know which tag to add to?)

Comment: I see you added `position:relative`.  What's the significance of that?

Comment: Not sure why, but this wouldn't work on the actual page I was doing this on.  The `<svg>` was `absolute` to the `body`, but making it `absolute` to the tag outside the `<form>` made it all work as I expect.  Thanks!